# What are the prerequisites to understand Affine Invariant Fourier Descriptors?

Tags: fourier-analysis, affine-geometry

I need to implement Affine Invariant Fourier Descriptors on matlab, the objective is to compare two objects one reference and other transformed by affine transformation for recognition, my problem is that I was able to reach up till fourier descriptor,implementation, but need to move now towards the affine invariant part. What I am able to get by reading some matter on the topic is that: 1)In affine invariant transformation we need to take a parameter that'It must be linear under an affine transformation' 2)The parameterizing function must yield the same parameterization independent of the initial representation of the contour

Now my problem is to understand that parameter and to find a way to implement this so that the descriptors I obtain of these two figures(one reference and one affine transformed) to be compared. Further I need to to program this, can anyone of you help me rescue from this blind stop?